# Java: need help with optimizing a part of code

Tags: java, optimization, transform

I have a simple code for transforming XML, but it is very time consuming (I have to repeat it many times). Does anyone have a recommendation how to optimize this code? Thanks.

**EDIT: This is a new version of the code.** I unfortunatelly can't reuse `Transformer`, since `XSLTRule`is in most of the cases different. I'm now reusing `TransformerFactory`. I'm not reading from files before this so I can't use `StreamSource`. Largest amount of time is spent on initialization of `Transformer`.

```
private static TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

public static String transform(String XML, String XSLTRule) throws TransformerException {

    Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(XML));
    Source xslInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(XSLTRule));

    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslInput);

    StringWriter resultWriter = new StringWriter();
    Result result = new StreamResult(resultWriter);
    transformer.transform(xmlInput, result);
    return resultWriter.toString();
}
```

Comment: Different XSL files every time? If not, cache the transformer. Plus, is this code slow in and of itself? What performance are you seeing?

Comment: Every time it's a different XML, but XSLTs repeat themselves (although there are many of them). I'm using a profiler and it says that bunch of time is spent on this method.

Comment: *Where* in this method? Compiling XSLTs is often slow, but if that's not where it's spending time... look at http://opensymphony.com/'s OSCore, as it has some optimized XML utilities that will cache transformers if it can.

Comment: @Joseph The largest amount of time is spent on initialization of `Transformer`. I'll think how to do the cache. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to skip the unnecessary conversion of the XML string to bytes (especially with a hardcoded, potentially incorrect encoding). You can use a `StringReader` and pass that to the `StreamSource` constructor. The same for the result: use a `StringWriter` and avoid the conversion.

Of course, if you call the method after converting your XML from a file (bytes) to a `String` in the first place (again with a potentially wrong encoding), it would be even better to have the `StreamSource` read from the file directly.

Comment: +1: unnecessary format conversion can waste lots of time. And they can easily introduce ugly bugs.

Comment: @Ivan: you're still doing an unnecessary and probably destructive String -> byte -> String conversion on the result stream. And yeah, caching the transformer instances could make a big improvement, depending on how often the same XSLT occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you apply an XSLT to an XML file. To speed things up, you can try compiling the XSLT, like with [XSLTC](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc_usage.html).

Comment: Although I get different XSLT on almost every invocation?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of a couple of minor things:

- The TransformerFactory could be reused.
- The Transformer could be reused if it is thread confined, and the XSL input is the same each time.
- If you can estimate the output size reasonably accurately, you could create the ByteArrayOutputStream with an initial size hint.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Michaels answer, you could potentially speed things up by not loading either the input or output xml entirely into memory yourself and make your api stream based.